# MongoDB group and sum with id as key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to to get the result of the aggregate function as `key:count`?

Example:

I have the following aggregate query:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$role",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

so the results come up as:

```
{ "_id" : "moderator", "count" : 469 }
{ "_id" : "superadmin", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "user", "count" : 2238 }
{ "_id" : "admin", "count" : 11 }
```

So that's all fine, but is there a way (perhaps using `$project`) of making results appear like this (i.e. with the `role` as the key and the `count` as the value):

```
{ "moderator": 469 }
{ "superadmin": 1 }
{ "user": 2238 }
{ "admin": 11 }
```

I could do that obviously by post-processing the result with JS, but my goal is to do that directly via the aggregate function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With MongoDb 3.6 and newer, you can leverage the use of **[`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)** operator and a **[`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)** pipeline to get the desired result. You would need to run the following aggregate pipeline:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": { "$toLower": "$role" },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "counts": {
                "$push": {
                    "k": "$_id",
                    "v": "$count"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$counts" }
        } 
    }    
])
```

---

For older versions, the [**`$cond`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) operator in the [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) pipeline step can be used effectively to evaluate the counts based on the role field value. Your overall aggregation pipeline can be constructed as follows to produce the result in the desired format:

```
db.users.aggregate([    
    { 
        "$group": { 
            "_id": null,             
            "moderator_count": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$role", "moderator" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "superadmin_count": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$role", "superadmin" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "user_count": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$role", "user" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "admin_count": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$role", "admin" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            } 
        }  
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0, 
            "moderator": "$moderator_count",
            "superadmin": "$superadmin_count",
            "user": "$user_count",
            "admin": "$admin_count"
        }
    }
])
```

---

From the comments trail, if you don't know the roles beforehand and would like to create the pipeline array dynamically, run the **[`distinct`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/)** command on the role field. This will give you an object that contains a list of the distinct roles:

```
var result = db.runCommand ( { distinct: "users", key: "role" } )
var roles = result.values;
printjson(roles); // this will print ["moderator", "superadmin", "user",  "admin"]
```

Now given the list above, you can assemble your pipeline by creating an object that will have its properties set using JavaScript's **[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** method. The following demonstrates this:

```
var groupObj = { "_id": null },
    projectObj = { "_id": 0 }

var groupPipeline = roles.reduce(function(obj, role) { // set the group pipeline object 
    obj[role + "_count"] = {
        "$sum": {
            "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$role", role ] }, 1, 0 ]
        }
    };
    return obj;
}, groupObj );

var projectPipeline = roles.reduce(function(obj, role) { // set the project pipeline object 
    obj[role] = "$" + role + "_count";
    return obj;
}, projectObj );
```

Use these two documents in your final aggregation pipeline as:

```
db.users.aggregate([groupPipeline, projectPipeline]);
```

Check the demo below.

```js
var roles = ["moderator", "superadmin", "user",  "admin"],
 groupObj = { "_id": null },
 projectObj = { "_id": 0 };

var groupPipeline = roles.reduce(function(obj, role) { // set the group pipeline object 
 obj[role + "_count"] = {
  "$sum": {
   "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$role", role ] }, 1, 0 ]
  }
 };
 return obj;
}, groupObj );

var projectPipeline = roles.reduce(function(obj, role) { // set the project pipeline object 
 obj[role] = "$" + role + "_count";
 return obj;
}, projectObj );

var pipeline = [groupPipeline, projectPipeline]

pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(pipeline, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks! But is there no way to do that without having to specify the roles? Half the magic of the aggregate function is using the ```$role``` wildcard..

Comment: Not sure of any other way since you have fixed values for the `role` field so getting the count of those values will solely rely on the evaluated logic in the `$group` pipeline, and that requires knowing the values beforehand.

Comment: I see.. thanks! I will upvote your answer but will let the question get lubricated some more :) After some days if no one comes up with something else I will accept it as THE answer.

Comment: Or, a long workaround would be to grab all the possible distinct values from the `role` field using the distinct command, `db.runCommand ( { distinct: "users", key: "role" } )`, do a bit of JavaScript manipulation to dynamically construct the `$group` document that goes into the pipeline using those distinct values as the object keys then run the pipeline.

Comment: Let me see if I can improve my answer and come up with the pipeline that satisfies the above algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map-reduce:

```
db.users.mapReduce(
  function map() { emit(this.role, 1); },
  function reduce(key, values) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
  },
  {
      out: { inline: 1 },
      finalize: function (key, reducedValue) {
          var obj = {};
          obj[key] = reducedValue;
          return obj;
      }
  }
)
```

and map only `value`